# struts2 jquery grid: data not displayed on grid

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid, struts2

I'm trying to use struts2-jquery grid plugin.
When debugging my gridmodel is getting updated correctly, but nothing is getting displayed on the grid.
This is my action class:

```
private List<Customer> gridModel; 
  private Integer             rows          ;

  private Integer             page         ;

  private String              sord;

  private String              sidx;

  private String              searchField;

  private String              searchString;

  private String              searchOper;

  private Integer             total         ;

  private Integer             records        ;

public String execute() throws Exception{
    try {
    List<Customer> list = new ArrayList<Customer>; 
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        Customer cust = new Customer("myName", 20, "myAdress", "23651336"); 
        list.add(cust); 
    }
    setGridModel(list); 
    setRecords(list.size());
    total =(int) Math.ceil((double)records / (double)rows);
    } catch( Exception e) {
        log.error("Error in JSON data : " +e.getMessage()); 
    }
    return SUCCESS; 

}

public List<Customer> getGridModel() {
    return gridModel;
}

public Integer getPage() {
    return page;
}

public void setPage(Integer page) {
    this.page = page;
}

public String getSearchField() {
    return searchField;
}

public void setSearchField(String searchField) {
    this.searchField = searchField;
}

public void setGridModel(List<Customer> gridModel) {
    this.gridModel = gridModel;
}

public String getSord() {
    return sord;
}

public void setSord(String sord) {
    this.sord = sord;
}

public String getSidx() {
    return sidx;
}

public void setSidx(String sidx) {
    this.sidx = sidx;
}

public Integer getRecords() {
    return records;
}

public void setRecords(Integer records) {
     this.records = records;

        if (this.records > 0 && this.rows > 0)
        {
          this.total = (int) Math.ceil((double) this.records / (double) this.rows);
        }
        else
        {
          this.total = 0;
        }
}

public String getSearchOper() {
    return searchOper;
}

public void setSearchOper(String searchOper) {
    this.searchOper = searchOper;
}

public Integer getTotal() {
    return total;
}

public void setTotal(Integer total) {
    this.total = total;
}

public String getSearchString() {
    return searchString;
}

public void setSearchString(String searchString) {
    this.searchString = searchString;
}

public Integer getRows() {
    return rows;
}

public void setRows(Integer rows) {
    this.rows = rows;
}
```

I add to my jsp the following grid definition:

```
<s:url id="remoteurl" action="jsontable"/>
<sjg:grid
    id="gridtable"
    caption="Listes "
    dataType="json"
    href="%{remoteurl}"
    pager="true"
    gridModel="gridModel"
    rowList="10,15,20"
    rowNum="15"
    rownumbers="true"
>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="name" index="name" title="Name"  />
    <sjg:gridColumn name="age" index="age" title="Age"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="adress" index="adress" title="Adress" />
    <sjg:gridColumn name="tel" index="tel" title="Tel"   />
</sjg:grid>
```

In struts.xml, I declare my action with result type json

```
<package name="default" extends="json-default,struts-default" namespace="/">

    <result-types>
        <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        <result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult" />
    </result-types>

    <action name="jsontable" class="com.web.action" method="execute" >
        <result name="success" type = "json"></result>
    </action>

</package>
```

Please, can you tell me what I'm missing

Comment: Any JavaScript Errors in your Console? Can you request your JSON Action manually and receive an valid JSON response?

Comment: Thx for your replay. There is no javascript error. And I have no JSON reponse, I think the problem is in JSON convertion

Comment: Does your class extend any class? Also can you show us what is returned when jsontable is called /using LiveHTTPHeader or whatever you use/

Comment: No my class does not exetend any class, but it implements SessionAware and ScopedModelDriven. Sorry but I don't undestand what do you mean with return jsontable using LiveHTTPHeader

Comment: @Sarroura if you have any getter method that is not needed on JSON result please add this annotation on the method -  @org.apache.struts2.json.annotations.JSON(serialize = false). What I meant was, can you show me the JSON response of your action using your browser

Comment: I tried to create another class action with the same code, and it works, I have my grid with values. But the problem now, is that I can't execute a submit button in the same jsp. I would like to know if there is any problem if I declare in the same form in my jsp a jquery grid and a sumit button with struts 2 tags (s:submit). Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved when I put my action in a new class action, not inside another action.